# How can I run a unit test when the tapped widget launches a Timer?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter

I have a Widget that, when clicked, saves an ID number, overlays a CircularProgressIndicator for 1000ms and then pops the progress indicator and routes the user to another page.

This bit with the ProgressIndicator and the Timer is new and has broken my unit test, which now gives me the following error:

```
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 574 pos 12: '() {
      'A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed.';
      return _fakeAsync.nonPeriodicTimerCount == 0;
    }': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding._verifyInvariants (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:574:12)
#3      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:415:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:392:14)
#8      AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:549:24)
#14     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:547:16)
#15     testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:54:50)
#16     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/declarer.dart:131:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/invoker.dart:200:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/invoker.dart:197:7)
#26     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test/src/backend/invoker.dart:196:5)
#27     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/declarer.dart:129:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test/src/backend/invoker.dart:322:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#43     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:385)
#44     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:414)
#45     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:148)
(elided 31 frames from class _AssertionError, class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package
dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)
```

This is what the broken test looks like:

```
testWidgets('Tapping item saves its id', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await launchApp(item, tester);
  await tester.tap(find.byConfig(item));

  expect(sameId(global_state.currentId, item.id), isTrue);
});
```

Is there some way to introduce a delay before disposing of the widget tree?  What are my other options?  Or am I wrong about the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

testWidgets automatically introduces a FakeAsync zone which lets you step through time. Use `pump` to advance time.

The error you're seeing, though, is because your widget isn't canceling the timer when it's disposed. Make sure that your Widget objects never allocate resources (like timers), and that your State objects always clean up any resources they allocate, in their `dispose` method.

Comment: Could you please give an example of resources that need to be cleaned up?

Answer (score 10):

Use `await tester.pumpAndSettle()`, by default it is using 100 milliseconds delay, but you can add you own value: `await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds:1))`

It can be useful if you test widget which uses Timer or some animated widget under the hood.

Here's a small example how to use it:

```
testWidgets('build with $state state', (tester) async {
        when(() => bloc.state).thenReturn(state);
        await blocTester.test(
          tester: tester,
          stateConfig: states[state]!,
        );
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      })
```

Answer (score 9):

For me, the problem was because I use the `visibility_detector` package, which uses a timer.  It actually states on their [GitHub page](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector):

> Widget tests that use VisibilityDetectors usually should set:
>
> ```
> VisibilityDetectorController.instance.updateInterval = Duration.zero
> ```

but I missed it.  Posting in case anyone else is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this inside a FakeAsync from Quiver's FakeAsync library:
https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/quiver/0.24.0/quiver.testing.async/FakeAsync-class.html

There are a number of examples of this pattern in the tests of the Flutter framework itself:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=FakeAsync